# Popup options menu horizontal not appearing in center

Tags: android, android-studio

[image]

i wanted to create a popup action menu for this fab.i used the quick action GitHub library but this is not coming centrally aligned.how to align it centrally.
https://github.com/piruin/quickaction

Answer (score 0):

You must first import the library into your project.
https://github.com/piruin/quickaction/blob/master/quickaction/src/main/res/layout/quick_action_horizontal.xml

if you set the width value of HorizontalScrollView here to match_parent, you get the look you want. If you also leave a space around the edges (android: layout_marginHorizontal = "40dp") the design you want will appear. Of course, apart from what I wrote, you should adjust your own corrections.

Comment: i tried it but same out is coming, further when i give a test run it reset the value to wrap content automatically